# Kettle pentaho memory clean up after the end of a transformation

Tags: memory, pentaho, kettle, pdi

Loading a csv file using kettle Pentaho into database the memory still remain not cleaned after the end of each transformation included in a job.

How I can force the clean up after the end of the transformation ?

I am using a suitable set up according to:

http://www.ibridge.be/?p=202

```
KETTLE_MAX_LOG_SIZE_IN_LINES=1     
KETTLE_MAX_JOB_TRACKER_SIZE=1     
KETTLE_CARTE_OBJECT_TIMEOUT_MINUTES=1     
KETTLE_MAX_JOB_ENTRIES_LOGGED=1     
KETTLE_STEP_PERFORMANCE_SNAPSHOT_LIMIT=1
```

Comment: How do you say the memory is not cleaned up?

Comment: well I have a series of 10 transformations in my job. I inspect the memory used using  "performance tab of my OS". At the beginning the memory used is 2G when i start spoon. When I start my job the memory used goes up to 8G at the end of the first transformation  where the csv is loaded.  At the end the memory used is still 8G. After the first transformation if I try to load another csv the process is incredibly slow and I geuss that the problem is that kettle doesn't have anough memory because 6G has been alredy spent in the first transformation

Comment: @Diego, can you publish your job & trans here? What are the CSVs' sizes? Are you executing each transformation in parallel?

Comment: the issue is reproducibile just with a simple transformation with: 1) csv Input) 2) insert into database (size 1.3GB 907373 rows for 93 columns) despite the complexity of my job. Kettle version 5.1.0

Comment: @Diego, does you transformation contain "Copy rows to result" step? In no, then it looks like a bug. Also, did you try Kettle 6.0 ? In the problem reproduces against the latest version, it make sense to report a bug

Comment: @Andrey: thanks for your help. I don't use "Copy rows to result". I will try Kettle 6.0 to check if it is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

This [source](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/187491-PDI-memory-leak-when-job-workflow-is-quot-too-long-quot#post_409610) offer a workaround :

> **Workaround: Dummy-Transformation with setting "clear list of result rows/files"**
> Regularly include a Dummy-Transformation where the "Advanced" settings:
>
> - "Clear list of result rows before execution?"
> - "Clear list of result files before execution?"
>
> ... are checked.

It can be found here:

[image: Picture to help finding it.]